# iPod software version too high?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ios7

I bought a new iPod touch today and I installed iOS 7 on it in order to beta test my new designs, color schemes, and speed enhancements. I'm running OSX 10.6.8 with Xcode 4.2 Build 4C199 (iOS 5). When I plugged my iPod in and pressed "use for development" in the xcode organizer I got an error saying that I couldn't use the iPod because the software version was too high. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xcode 5, [which you can get from the same place you got iOS 7 from](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) (provided you're a registered developer).

Comment: I cannot because I don't have a high enough OSX

Comment: XCode 5 runs on MacOS 10.6.8, b.t.w.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the iOS version, you can not build to an iOS version higher than that of the SDK you have installed. Update your Xcode to the version that comes with the SDK that matches the iOS version you wish to build to.

Comment: I cannot because I don't have a high enough OSX

Comment: @Coder404 Sorry, but you might have to upgrade. I haven't been able to find any evidence that this Xcode version can be persuaded to run on that OS X version.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. I have iOS 7 beta on a test device and once it was used with Xcode 5, I had no further issues using Xcode 4.6 (and a Base SDK of iOS 6.1) to debug apps on the iOS 7 device. This is a great way to test existing iOS 6 apps to be sure they will work as-is under iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the Xcode 5 beta

Comment: I cannot because I don't have a high enough OSX

Comment: Yup.  I just went through that.  Had to upgrade my OSX before I could upgrade my Xcode before I could debug with my upgraded iOS.  Didn't want to upgrade my OSX because I wanted to wait for 10.9, but Apple left me no choice.